# How to return True or False for a function which has a number argument?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I have two dictionaries defined `<Suits>` and `<Breaking_Bad>` which have the same keys.

```
Suits = {'name': 'Suits', 'seasons': 8, 'status': 'Ongoing'}    
Breaking_Bad = {'name': 'Breaking Bad', 'seasons': 5, 'status': 'Completed'}
```

I am asked to write a function argument called `high_seasons` (`tv_show`, `seasons`) that takes `tv_show` as a 1st argument and seasons (represented as a number) as the 2nd argument and returns True if the given `tv_show` season is greater than or equal to the provided season and returns `False` otherwise.

Here is my code:

```
def high_seasons (tv_show, seasons):    
    tv_show.keys() == seasons.keys()    
    if tv_show ['seasons'] >= seasons ['seasons']:    
        return True    
    else:    
        return False

high_seasons(Suits, 7) ## Expected result True        
high_seasons(Breaking_Bad, 7) ## Expected result False
```

I am receiving the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

Comment: The error is in this line `tv_show.keys() == seasons.keys()`. The variable `tv_show` and `seasons` are `int type` in this context, like your exception say

Comment: Thanks Kafel. I do realize that the issue is lies in that line you mentioned. However, I must define the 2nd argument as a number. For example, 
 high_seasons **(Suits, Breaking_Bad)**  returns **True** as expected. high_seasons **(Suits, 5)** returns an  **error**

Answer (score 2):

You need to decide on the type of object your function accepts first. From your description, I think you want to design your function signature such as:

```
def high_seasons(tv_show: dict, seasons: int):
    pass
```

However, in your logical code block, you tried calling `seasons.keys()`. This is the part that's throwing the error above. As it says, an int object does not have the keys attribute. Therefore, to implement the signature above, your code should look something like:

```
def high_seasons (tv_show, seasons):       
    if tv_show['seasons'] >= seasons:    
        return True    
    else:    
        return False
```

**Edit**
Updated to use the syntactically correct way to declare variable types explicitly. Credits go to @Luna.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It was so simple after all.

Answer (score 2):

```
def high_seasons(tv_show: dict, seasons: int) -> bool:
    return int(tv_show.get('seasons')) >= seasons
```

Can you solve your problem?